# Prevent snapshots of VPS

Tags: linux, privacy, server

Pretend I have a server. Is there anyway to prevent (or make more difficult) the administrator from taking snapshots? Feel free to give me a software way, or suggest if I should change server types; dedicated server be better than a VPS, or KVM VPS be better than an OpenVZ VPS?

I know certain countries have laws, but I have trust issues. I am also aware that it is possible to dump the RAM and find the decryption key (in the event that the VPS is encrypted).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a VPS the administrator of the underlying computer system can easily do snapshots and you cannot prevent this from inside the VPS. Similar you cannot prevent snapshots of a process by somebody having administrative access to the underlying operating system.

The only way to protect sensitive data inside a process/VM is to obfuscate them in order to make it harder to extract information from the snapshot. Better yet don't even have any sensitive data inside the process/VM, that is do your sensitive computations on a system where only you have control like done with [Cloudflare Keyless SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/keyless-ssl/). Or use hardware where nobody except you have access, but even in this case somebody might have tampered with the hardware or it might backdoors inside by design.

Comment: Thanks. When you say obfuscate do you mean source codes, or something else? Sadly I can't host from my own hardware - it must be from a dedi or VPS.

Comment: Sorry to double post but I'm unsure how Cloudfare's keyless SSL would help me, struggling to understand the technology.

Comment: @user5510281: With keyless SSL the private key is not on-site and can thus not be extracted when a VPS snapshot is done. Instead the necessary cryptographic operations are done off-site at a remote system and the private key is only there. This is in a way similar to smart cards or other hardware security modules where the private key is also not accessible by the computer. And with obfuscate I mean whatever you can obfuscate - if the secret is plain in some PHP file you must obfuscate it, if it is at some location in memory you must obfuscate it there etc - easy to say but hard to do.